# Include all predicted intent scores - not working

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

My LUIS model used to return all intent scores when queried. However, now it only returns the top intent, entities and sentiment analysis.

I have "Include all predicted intent scores" checked on and I publish and still am only getting back topScoringIntent, entities, and sentimentAnalysis.

We're working on a new feature that is going to take advantage of the score breakdown of all intents and this is blocking us.

Answer (score 1):

"Include all predicted intent scores" is merely UI setting by -> you may see changing the url value in "Keys and Endpoints" section in column "Endpoint" as you can see below.

[image]

---

If you would like to have all intents and scores you need to use following url when executing http GET towards LUIS:

> https://yourlocation.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/yourAppId?subscription-key=yourSubscriptionKey**&verbose=true**&timezoneOffset=-360&q=Test
>   test

If you omit

> verbose=true

in the query string or set its value to false then you get only topScoringIntent and eventually sentiment if its detection is turned on.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for!

Comment: ' "include all predicted intent scores" is merely UI setting by '

What exactly does merely a UI setting mean? What does it actually do then?

Comment: It does what is visible on the screenshot - it changes the url for one LUIS application and one subscriptionkey that the user may click at.- or copy.

Comment: The screenshot shows the same url twice with no changes. Toggling that switch does not add the '&verbose=true' flag onto the url. If it did, I would never have had to ask this question :)

Comment: @BrianC I'm sorry you are mistaken. Please try it carefully again the url changes as you toggle the Enabled/Disabled. I just tried it again to make my answer proof to latest changes of the UI with success. PS: please check the screenshot carefully too - the results are not the same!